# How to solve a particular nonhomogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Does anyone know how to solve the particular part in a non-homogeneous recurrence relation?

I know how to solve a homogeneous one, I just can't seem to understand how to find the particular one?

Is there some kind of formula for that?

Here's an example of one:$$a_{n+2}-4a_{n+1}+4a_n=2^n \sin(\frac{\pi n}{3})$$

I know that homogeneous part has two zeros, $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are both $2 $ meaning that the homogeneous part would look like: 
$$ a_n= (An+B)2^n$$

I don't know how to calculate the non-homogeneous part though. Do you just guess it? If so how? or Is there some kind or a formula/recipe?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is more an art than a science... say your recurrence is $a_{n + 2} + \alpha a_{n + 1} + \beta = f(n)$. The *characteristic equation* is $x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0$, say it has roots $r_1$ and $r_2$. For the homogeneous part, $a_{n + 2} + \alpha a_{n + 1} + \beta = 0$ has solutions of the form $a_n = c_1 r_1^n + c_2 r_2^n$ if $r_1 \ne r2$ and $a_n = (c_1 n + c_2) r_1^n$ when $r_1 = r_2$. Now for the particular solution:

- If $f(n) = c r^n$, and $r \ne r_1$ and $r \ne r_2$, a solution has the form $C r^n$. Substitute to get $C$.
- If $f(n) = c r_1^n$, and $r_1 \ne r_2$, a solution has the form $C n r_1^n$.
- If $f(n) = c r_1^n$, and $r_1 = r_2$, a solution has the form $C n^2 r_1^n$.
- For linear combinations of the above, try linear combinations of the general forms given.

For other forms of $f$, things get hairy...

Comment: thank you so much for the reply! the biggest problem for me are the ones where i have as f(n) sin,cos, tg and ctg. if you click on the example link you can see an example of the one that causes me problems (sorry i don't know how to insert equations)

Comment: You can write $\exp(i x) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$, use that to transform sines/cosines into exponentials and apply the above, and go back at the end. Other trigonometric functions get you into hot water...

Comment: so in that case, how would the particular part of my example look? can you use step by step  method?